# Assets pipeline, css works but not js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My site has problems with finding javascripts and some of the images. It cannot display the images that is located within folders in the assets/images/ and none of the js and jquery.

The css works fine. But the weird thing is that when I moved the images down one folder to the assets folder, they still didn't work. Been trying to find something in assets pipeline guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

But without a result. Could it be related to some precompiling? I tried some precompliling, but no changes.

I'm open for all suggestions! Thank you.

Edit: After som more research I found that it has generated most of the files in a folder in public/assets, and it grabs all files from there. I don't know why it generates them to that folder nor how to direct it to grab them from app/assets/javascripts.

Comment: Is this is production or development mode? Is this a new app or upgraded?

Comment: @RichardHulse It is in production mode and is a new app.

Answer (score 0):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails to find out how to change the asset path.

Comment: I already went through all those steps.. I dont know how the precompliing works, but it has created another aplication.js file that is located in public/assets folder. And when I'm removing that assets folder the css and all images stop working. So obviously it's reading all files from the wrong folder! So I have to direct it to the right folder somehow..

Comment: I'm rather confused with these: "...it has generated most of the files in a folder in public/assets, and it grabs all files from there..." and "when I'm removing that assets folder the css and all images stop working..." Btw, is this a new rails app, or are you upgrading from older version?